# After Content update from Ajax jQuery not work properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I have a content slider, that is working fine on the first page of ajax loaded content, But when I go to the next page from ajax loaded content and then I click on `#readyslider` to update sliding animation for newly loaded future content, then the slider becomes glitches. and it does not work properly, time and fade all event go in trouble. Why?

And just like that as I go to the next page so on, the slider problems get worse.

I google for that and tried so many other techies but didn't work Like jQuery  noConflict https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

I changed all `$` to `j` with `jQuery  noConflict` like that:

But it didn't work.

**EDIT :** i have added whole html and css code of my slider, try to click `ReadySlider` button more then one time and you see the problem.

**My Practice:**

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(document).ready(function () {

j(document).on("click", '#readyslider', function(event) { 
    setTimeout(function () { 

var interval;
var interval = false;
j("#subttlslider > div:gt(0)").hide();

function updateDiv() {
  j('#subttlslider > div:first')
    .fadeOut(600)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(400)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#subttlslider');
}

j("#nextclick").click(function(){

    $('#subttlslider > div:first-child')
    .fadeOut(600)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(400)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#subttlslider');
});

j("#prevclick").click(function(){
    $('#subttlslider > div:first-child')
    .fadeOut(0)
     $('#subttlslider > div:last-child')
    .prependTo('#subttlslider') 
    .fadeOut();
    $('#subttlslider > div:first-child').fadeIn();
});


j(".play").click(function() {
  if(!interval){
    interval = setInterval(updateDiv, 5000);
  }
  

});
```

**and My whole slider default code is:**

```js
$(document).on("click", '#readyslider', function(event) { 

    setTimeout(function () { 

var interval;
var interval = false;
$("#subttlslider > div:gt(0)").hide();

function updateDiv() {
  $('#subttlslider > div:first')
    .fadeOut(600)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(400)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#subttlslider');
}

$("#nextclick").click(function(){

    $('#subttlslider > div:first-child')
    .fadeOut(600)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(400)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#subttlslider');
});

$("#prevclick").click(function(){
    $('#subttlslider > div:first-child')
    .fadeOut(0)
     $('#subttlslider > div:last-child')
    .prependTo('#subttlslider') 
    .fadeOut();
    $('#subttlslider > div:first-child').fadeIn();
});


$(".play").click(function() {
  if(!interval){
    interval = setInterval(updateDiv, 5000);
  }
  

});

$(".pause").click(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = false;
});

    }, 10);

});
```

```css
#subttlslider>div {
  position: absolute;

}

#subttlslider {
    font-family: Four C Maya !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    background: linear-gradient(
90deg, rgba(162,162,162,1) 0%, rgba(252,252,255,1) 21%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 64%, rgba(162,162,162,1) 100%);
    color: black !important;
    box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0) 0px 1px 10px 1px inset !important;
    
    width: 552px !important;
    height: 283px !important;
        text-align: center !important;
    float: left !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 6px solid yellow;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 17px 3px #000;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size:3em;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
   
  }
  
#subttlslidermaindiv {
position: absolute;
    width: 552px !important;
    height: 283px !important;
}





/** slideIn Left Right out **/

.slideInLeft {
    animation: slideInLeft 500ms both
}
@keyframes slideInLeft {
    from {
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }

    to {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


------
<button id="readyslider">ReadySlider</button>
<button class="play">play ⏯︎</button>
<button class="pause">⏸︎</button>
<button id="prevclick">⏪ Prev </button>
<button id="nextclick">Next ⏩</button>
-------




<div id="subttlslidermaindiv">
<div id="subttlslider" class="detailcontainer">
<div class='slideInLeft'>1) There is a lot of stress around us whole day which creates lot of hindrance in our mind.

</div>
<div class='slideInLeft'>2) The stress can arise at office, at our home, in some relations or in anything else.

 </div>
<div class='slideInLeft'>3) People while handling these kinds of stress doesn’t get the chance to see the beauty of life.

</div>
<div class='slideInLeft'>4) We forget that there is something more in our life which is valuable and beautiful.

</div>
<div class='slideInLeft'>5) God has given us plenty of good things like the beauty of nature in our life.

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I think is the problem is created from injecting slider code again and again, by clicking on `#readyslider`  button when my ajax content Update...

But I really didn't know what is another solution for that is to run slider every time after going to ajax next page content without a glitch.

Can I get help with that plz..! a Lovely Hug in Advance :)

Comment: it's easier to help you if you add HTML too.

Comment: @Neeraj
How and Where i need to add HTML plz explain

Comment: @Neeraj i have added Full HTML source, now plz check

Comment: Where did you put your scripts ? Is there any partial html?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just make it so it only gets activated once?

```
var clicked = false;       // New
$(document).on("click", '#readyslider', function (event) {
    if (!clicked) {        // New
        clicked = true;    // New
        setTimeout(function () {
            // ...Same...
        }, 10);
    }
});
```